# No access to raspberry pi after upgrading to windows 11

Tags: networking, ssh, raspberry-pi, windows-11

My Computer was updated to Windows 11 and since then, i can't reach my Pi anymore.

Pings do work, but neigther ssh nor http can be accessed. I tried different devicis within my network and it worked. I tried turning off both firewalls, no result.
I also can access the pi from my dyndns over cellular connection from my phone.

Also, i tried with a different SD and OS: same result.

What can i do, to get access again?

Comment: Are you in a local network? Are you accessing by IP?

Comment: Yes, I am in the local network. From any other device it does work. Just not from my Windows 11 Computer.

Comment: Note : You only have 10 days to rollback to Windows 10.

Comment: Update: even now back to Windows 10 ... the Computer can not connect to the pi ... every other device does, internal and external connection.

Comment: I have the same issue. I upgraded my laptop to Windows 11, and now it cannot see any local computers on the network. I can't even ping them from the Command tool

Comment: @Bengt it SEEM, that you need windows 11 Pro for this feature ... after i gave it another try, i bought the pro license ... and i worked flawless

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After Buying a License for Windows 11 Pro, it all worked fine.

Comment: You don't need the "pro" version of windows in order to connect to an rpi

Comment: well ... with the home version it did not work ...

Comment: Correlation does not imply causation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my laptop. After the upgrade to Windows 11, Tailscale (home VPN) had been activated to autostart. After deactivating/killing Tailscale and making sure it only starts on demand, I can access my Raspberry Pi's again.